# "Not much I can hand to you this very moment"

Tags: meaning, phrases, sentence

What's the meaning of this sentence?

> Not much I can hand to you this very moment.

Comment: Note that it is a colloquial form of "There is not much that I can hand to you at this very moment".

Comment: "Not much I can *hand to* you this moment" definitely implies the transfer of physical objects. I'd expect "Not much I can *give you*..." (or, *let you have*) if being asked for information in verbal form only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- not much = little
- hand to someone = give to someone
- this very moment = right now

So, it means “there is little I can give you right now”.

Answer (score 5):

A phrase like this might be used by someone who needs to give you bad news but at the same time wants to spare your feelings.

When spoken, it might be said with a sympathetic expression and maybe added emphasis

> Not ***much*** I can hand to you ***this moment***

...when the truth might be that there is **nothing** to give you, and there might never be.